# Link large number of cells to different files in one go?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a folder with lets say, 500 further sub-folders within it.

In Excel, there is a document with a corresponding list of numbers, which I link through to manually.

AE 0001 through to AE 0500 for example.

I currently do this by hand for each file. This is a killer as you can imagine. I recently had a helpful chap explain how to generate large numbers of those folders, and now I'm wondering if there is a way to have Excel look at that column with those sequential numbers and link through to the corresponding files without me having to repeat the manual process for each one?

Comment: " I recently had a helpful chap explain" - thanks ;)

Comment: Bwahaha... No problems. You really did save me hours of work and took a lot of weight off my shoulders. :)

Answer (score 0):

Type this into A1:
`=HYPERLINK("AE "&TEXT(ROWS($A$1:A1);"0000"))`
... assuming you put the rest of the copies below (rows).

Use the "fill handle" to get the copies.

To get the full path to the files/folders correctly, just add the path after `"` before `AE "`.

**NOTE 1:** A second optional parameter to `URL()` allows to define what to show in the cell instead of the URL (first parameter) itself.

***NOTE 2:*** Regional and Language settings tells if you need to replace `;` in the formula above with `,` or vice versa.

---

In case of trouble:
Please verify that the path and filename is correct by changing the first cell content

to
`="\\path\to\file\Prepended name AE "&TEXT(ROWS($A$1:A1);"0000")`

or
`="C:\path\to\file\Prepended name AE "&TEXT(ROWS($A$1:A1);"0000")`

If the name seems ok from a glance, then copy the name (Copy special > Paste Text) and try it from "cmd" / or "Run" (Windows-R).

Comment: Hum. Can't seem to get this to work. It keeps saying we found a problem with the formula. So the full link to the folder which contains the 500 other folders would be: 
\\xx\xx\xxxx\xx\xx\xx\xx

So should it read:

=HYPERLINK("\\xx\xx\xxxx\xx\xx\xx\xx AE "&TEXT(ROWS($A$1:A1);"0000"))

?

I've tried various setups and it keeps coming back with an error.

Comment: Response moved into Answer-posting.

Comment: I've got it now. I changed the ';' for ',' and that seemed to fix it. It now links through properly. Is there a way I can hide the massive link though?

So on the spreadsheet is shows the full link, but I need it to show AE 0001, etc.

Thanks for your patience with this!

Comment: Sorry for the `,` versus `;` confusion! Which one to use is locale dependent (Windows: Excel settings and/or Region and Language in Control panel). See above for more.